# Onelogin authentication

Tags: onelogin

I have a native mobile application in iOS and Android. I would like to add the app authentication via onelogin. How can I integrate the authentication in my mobile app. Is there any option to communicate onelogin mobile app to my app. Could you please give me an idea about how to implement the onelogin authentication in my mobile app.

Thanks
Shihas

Answer (score 1):

If you look at what the Big Guys do (Google, Slack, etc.) they embed a browser-based SAML flow into their native applications.

Beyond that, OneLogin has OpenID Connect right now and that can similarly provide for a web flow to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

One login offers javascript apis for authentication please refer.
https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/getting-started/dev-overview.
I successfully implemented it in php.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for this:

1. As correctly mentioned by John Offenhartz, OneLogin has SAML, OIDC as well as you can embed OneLogin's page in your application. With approach you need to develop SAML/OIDC in mobile application.
2. But for your use case I think you can use OneLogin's Authentication APIs which simply tells you if the credentials are valid or not.
   Please find link below:
   https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/create-session-login-token
   With this approach you just need check OneLogin's response for the API call.